# permutations gone wrong

Tags: vb.net, string, permutation

I have written code to implement an algorithm I found on string permutations. What I have is an arraylist of words ( up to 200) and I need to permutate the list in levels of 5. Basically group the string words in fives and permutated them. What I have takes the first 5 words generates the permutations and ignores the rest of the arraylist?
Any ideas appreciated.

```
Private Function permute(ByVal chunks As ArrayList, ByVal k As Long) As ArrayList
        ReDim ItemUsed(k)
        pno = 0
        Permutate(k, 1)

        Return chunks
    End Function


    Private Shared Sub Permutate(ByVal K As Long, ByVal pLevel As Long)

        Dim i As Long, Perm As String
        Perm = pString ' Save the current Perm
        ' for each value currently available


        For i = 1 To K

            If Not ItemUsed(i) Then
                If pLevel = 1 Then
                    pString = chunks.Item(i)
                    'pString = inChars(i)
                Else
                    pString = pString & chunks.Item(i)
                    'pString += inChars(i)
                End If
                If pLevel = K Then 'got next Perm
                    pno = pno + 1
                    SyncLock outfile
                        outfile.WriteLine(pno & " = " & pString & vbCrLf)
                    End SyncLock
                    outfile.Flush()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                ' Mark this item unavailable
                ItemUsed(i) = True
                ' gen all Perms at next level
                Permutate(K, pLevel + 1)
                ' Mark this item free again
                ItemUsed(i) = False
                ' Restore the current Perm 
                pString = Perm
            End If
        Next
```

K above is = to 5 for the number of words in one permutation but when I change the for loop to the arraylist size I get an error of index out of bounds

Comment: What do you mean by “in levels of 5”?

Comment: Why do you use `SyncLock`? Is the code used in a multithreaded environment? Not advised! What is `pString` and why is it not a parameter?

Comment: It might help us figure out what you're trying to do if you could provide sample input and desired output for your function.

Answer (score 0):

Index out of bounds error usually happens when you start the loop from 1 to length. The the for loop as following.

---

```
    For i  = 0 to array.length - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error.

When you do

For i = 1 To K

The last value of i will be the size of your array.

chunks.Item(i)

Will crash when i equals the size of the array since the index starts at 0.

I would suggest you change your for loop to

For i = 0 To K - 1

Or you change the way you access the values in your arrays to

chunks.Item(i-1)

Answer (score 0):

C++ Permutation

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(const int *v, const int size)
{
  if (v != 0) 
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
      printf("%4d", v[i] );
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
} // print


void permute(int *v, const int start, const int n)
{  
  if (start == n-1) {
    print(v, n);
  }
  else {
    for (int i = start; i < n; i++) {
      int tmp = v[i];

      v[i] = v[start];
      v[start] = tmp;
      permute(v, start+1, n);
      v[start] = v[i];
      v[i] = tmp;
    }
  }
}


main()
{
  int v[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
  permute(v, 0, sizeof(v)/sizeof(int));
}
```